# Button won't work in jQuery

Tags: jquery

On clicking the button, an alert message saying 'hi' should pop up. This doesn't happen. Please help.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:/jquery-1.7.1.min">

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myButton").click(function()
{
  alert('hi'); 
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="myButton">Some button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/cSXBN/1/ - are you sure that's the path to jquery? You should also wrap your js in `<script>` tags.

Comment: Yes, I also think the script-source is wrong and so jQuery is not loaded.

Comment: At least it should be `C:/jquery-1.7.1.min.js` and close that tag + open a new for the inline script

Comment: Inline JavaScript will not be executed when you specify an external file. You need to have two `<script>` tags.

Comment: @Stijn I believe that's the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `C:/jquery-1.7.1.min` to `file:///C:/jquery-1.7.1.min` and put each script inside it's own script tag.

```
<script src='file:///C:/jquery-1.7.1.min'></script>
<script>
  // your JS here
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The script tags are not valid, change it to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/jquery-1.7.1.min"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myButton").click(function()
{
  alert('hi'); 
});
});
</script>
```

Just a guess, but the first row is maybe:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```